# Is it possible to use % with double? If not what can I do?

Tags: c

Going to post the whole code so if there is something else you can help me.
The idea of the program is to know if the inserted number is multiple of 5, power of 10 or a perfect square (I'm not English, a bit unsure if this word is the one I'm looking for).

```
int main (void){

    int i,b=0,rqi; 
    printf("Insert a number from 1 to 10000: ");
    scanf("%d",i);
    double rq=sqrt(i),p=log(i);

    if(i%5==0){
        printf("It's a multiple of 5\n");
        b=1;
    }

    if(p%1==0){
        int pi=p;
        printf("It's a power of 10 (%d=10^%d)\n",i,pi);
        b=1;
    }

    if(rq%1.0==0){
        rqi=rq;
        printf("It's a perfect square (%d = %d*%d)\n",i,rqi,rqi);
    }

    if(b==0){
        printf("It doesn't satisfies any condition.\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The errors I'm getting are

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d",i);
  ^

error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘double’ and ‘int’)
  if(p%1==0)
      ^

invalid operands to binary % (have ‘double’ and ‘double’)
  if(rq%1.0==0)
```

Also, I learned a bit of java and not C, is there a way to make a boolean or making an int 0 or 1 is the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 scanf("%d",i);
```

Pass address of `int` .Write like this -

```
 scanf("%d",&i);
```

`%` operator cannot be used on `double` or `float` . Remainder is just concerned for integer values .

Use [`fmod`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fmod.htm) function for the above task to get remainder.

Like this you can do this and incorporate it in your `if` condition-

```
fmod(p,1.0) // gives remainder of p divided by 1.0
```

But probably don't compare `double` values using `==`.

Comment: Why was the downvote ?  Please let me know the reason .

Comment: Get Used , strange things happen in here :).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should check [fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) function.

Also, if you want to check whether a double is of integer's range or not, you can check if it's value is equal to it's floor's value or not, using [floor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/) fucntion.

```
if(double_num == floor(double_num)) return 1;
else return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically dealing with integers here. Floating-point arithmetic has its inaccuracies; it might be better to do the comparison with integers instead.

```
int is_square(unsigned int x)
{
    int r = sqrt(x) + 0.5;

    return (r*r == x);
}
```

Here, a (crudely) rounded integer root is calculated first. Then you check back whether squaring it gives you back your original number.

```
int is_power10(unsigned int x)
{
    while (x && x % 10 == 0) x /= 10;

    return (x == 1);
}
```

Strip off trailing zeros. If all that's left is a 1, you've got a power of 10.